# Direct input or Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I would like the end user to be able to enter a value OR the spreadsheet will automatically populate a formula. I would also like it to re-populate the formula if the direct input is deleted. Currently the below code does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal target As Range)

If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then

Range("B8").Formula = "=IF($B$1=""DC"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$I:$I,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),IF($B$1=""Division"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$M:$M,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0)" _
& ",IF($B$1=""GBU"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)&>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$N:$N,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),IF($B$1=""Rollup"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$O:$O,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),""""))))"

End If
End Sub
```

Edit:

New formula looks like this after I added it to the old sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("C1").ClearContents
End If

If target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing And target.Value = "" Then

Range("B8").Formula = "=IF($B$1=""DC"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$I:$I,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),IF($B$1=""Division"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$M:$M,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0)" _
& ",IF($B$1=""GBU"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)&>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$N:$N,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),IF($B$1=""Rollup"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K,'TY Data'!$A:$A,5101200,'TY Data'!$L:$L,VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1,Dates!$A:$D,3,0),'TY Data'!$D:$D,""AP0345R"",'TY Data'!$O:$O,'Wage Run'!$D$1),0),""""))))"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `Worksheet_Change1`? it can not have that name, it will never fire.

Comment: Also you will want to test that the target is empty Put this in the If before the Then `And Target.Value = ""`

Comment: ok that helped. At least its firing now... but now I'm getting a debug error on the range("b8").Forumla part.

Comment: In the bit of the formula that says `IF($B$1=""GBU"",IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)&>=VLOOKUP`, the `&` shouldn't be there.

Comment: BTW - that formula could probably be simplified **a LOT** if you put your `IF` around just the part of the `SUMIFS` that is changing - ie `SUMIFS(.... ,IF($B$1=""DC"",'TY Data'!$I:$I,IF($B$1=""Division"",'TY Data'!$M:$M,IF($B$1=""GBU"",'TY Data'!$N:$N,'TY Data'!$O:$O))),'Wage Run'!$D$1)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not disabling event triggers. When you write the formula into B8, the Worksheet_Change is going to run on top of itself. If the formula happens to return `""` then it is going to keep running on top of itself until you crash.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
        Case "B1"
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        Case "B8"
            If Not Target.HasFormula Then _
                Target.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1, Dates!$A:$D, 3, FALSE), " & _
                                          "SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K, " & _
                                                 "'TY Data'!$A:$A, 5101200, " & _
                                                 "'TY Data'!$L:$L, VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1, Dates!$A:$D, 3, FALSE), " & _
                                                 "'TY Data'!$D:$D, ""AP0345R""," & _
                                                 "INDEX('TY Data'!$I:$O, 0, LOOKUP($B$1, {""DC"",""Division"",""GBU"",""Rollup""}, {1,5,6,7})), 'Wage Run'!$D$1), 0), """")"
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

On a related topic, this is my modification to your formula. In B8 as,

```
=IFERROR(IF(MAX('TY Data'!$L:$L)>=VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1, Dates!$A:$D, 3, FALSE),
      SUMIFS('TY Data'!$K:$K, 'TY Data'!$A:$A, 5101200,
                              'TY Data'!$L:$L, VLOOKUP('Wage Run'!$F$1, Dates!$A:$D, 3, FALSE),
                              'TY Data'!$D:$D, "AP0345R",
                              INDEX('TY Data'!$I:$O, 0, LOOKUP($B$1, {"DC","Division","GBU","Rollup"}, {1,5,6,7})), 'Wage Run'!$D$1), 0), "")
```

The last line with `INDEX` is where the `OR(B1={"DC","Division","GBU","Rollup"})` comes into play.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much... I love smart people. One final question. Is there a way to allow direct input into cell B8? Such as if they wanted to overwrite the formula with a value and then if that value is deleted, it reverts back to the formula.

Comment: Change `If Not Target.HasFormula Then _` to `If IsEmpty(Target) Then _` Using `If Target = ""` does not preclude Target having a formula that returns `""`. The `""` is not truly blank but a 'zero-length string'; only `IsEmpty` defines a truly blank cell.

Comment: You are awesome! Worked perfectly :)